# How to set PHPStorm to check for variable usage in required/included files? How to check variable definition in required/included files?

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I `require` or `include` a file in PHPStorm, it's not being able to detect that a variable defined in the main file is being used in that file that is being required/included. Same thing with the variable in the included/required file, it shows as not defined.

Here's an example for clarity:

Main file (let's say `main.php`):

```
<?php
$var1 = "hi";
require "next.php";
```

While here is the "required" `next.php` file:

```
<?php
echo "<p>".$var1."</p>";
```

The code works fine but on PHPStorm, `$var1` shows as unused in the `main.php` file while it shows as undefined in the `next.php` file.

I've seen several answers on SO on how to disable the warnings but that's not what I want. I want PHPStorm to recognize this variable as used and defined in the called and calling modules respectively.

Is this possible? Or am I asking the wrong questions?

If anyone's wondering why I'm doing this, I'm trying to separate logic from structure ala-MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that just looking at `next.php` **by itself**, the variable is unequivocally undefined. There's no guarantee how `next.php` will be executed. You cannot restrict the file to only be executed when included from another file. You *can* execute this file by itself, in which case it will fail. Or you can `include` it from infinitely many other files which do not set this variable, in which case it will fail.

That is why PhpStorm is nagging you about this undefined variable. It *is* bad coding style because it *can* fail in any number of circumstances.

Comment: MVC does not preclude proper variable passing. If you write everything as functions or classes with explicit parameters, and use a templating system which decouples variables (e.g. Twig) or you at least use the necessary annotations for PhpStorm, it won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions why this is not implemented in PhpStorm by default. 
I can only suggest you to create custom plugin for your project and i can help you to make it.

You can view video with custom goto plugin. It is relative with your problem. In view file navigate to variable defined in controller file. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVy2MJGJ6LM

Comment: I guess you're saying instead of following the regular MVC style, we should use classes instead?

Answer (score -2):

I am often using an init.php script where for example the db connection ($db) is made.
If the connection changes, only one place has to be edited.
In my scripts which are doing the work I now always start with